# Embedded Linux. Symbol lookup error

Tags: linux, embedded

I made userdef.c for adding some function otsu_Threshold and onBinarOtzu.
The function library header file is **pxa_lib.h** and I typed function like this

> void otzu_Threshold(unsigned char* orgImg, unsigned char* outImg, int height, int width);
>
> void onBinarOtzu(unsigned char* m_InImg);

In camera.c that is in Folder 'demo', I typed

> '#include < pxa_lib.h >
>
> ....
>
> ....
>
> onBinarOtzu(vidbuf->ycbcr.y);

MakeFile

> CC=/usr/local/arm-linux-4.1.1/bin/arm-linux-gcc
>
> CFLAGS+= -mcpu=iwmmxt -mtune=iwmmxt -mabi=aapcs-linux  \
>
> ```
>   -Iinclude/ -DDEBUG_BUILD
> ```
>
> LFLAGS+=-Llib/ -lpxadev
>
> .PHONY: all compile install-host install-target clean clean-local \
>
> uninstall-host uninstall-target
>
> all: compile install-host install-target
>
> compile: lib/libpxadev.so bin/camera
>
> lib/libpxadev.so: driver/camera.o driver/overlay2.o driver/userdef.o
>
> $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -shared -W1,-soname,libpxadev.so -o lib/libpxadev.so $^
>
> bin/camera: demo/camera.c
>
> $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS) -o $@ $^
>
> install-host:
>
> install-target:
>
> clean: clean-local uninstall-host uninstall-target
>
> clean-local:
>
> -rm -f lib/* driver/*.o
>
> -rm -f bin/*
>
> uninstall-host:
>
> -rm -f $(PXA_HOST_LIB_DIR)/libpxadev.so
>
> uninstall-target:
>
> $(SUDO) rm -f $(PXA_TARGET_BIN_DIR)/camera
>
> $(SUDO) rm -f $(PXA_TARGET_LIB_DIR)/libpxadev.so

I made binary file and transmitted in robot by minicom,zmodem.

But, error had occured.

> [root@WENDERS root]# [root@WENDERS root]# ./camera
> PXA_CAMERA:choose MT.... sensor
> PXA_CAMERA:choose MT.... sensor
> camera_config :  streamparm.type = 1
> count = 3
> width=320, height=240
> ./camera: symbol lookup error: ./camera: undefined symbol: onBinarOtzu

What sould I do...

ps. I'm sorry. I can't English well...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you linked to shared libraries while compiling, but they aren't loaded on the target.

You'll have to add the libraries somewhere Linux can find them, perhaps in `/usr/lib` or `/lib`, or somewhere specified by the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable. Exactly how you do this is dependent on the environment you have set up.